# Airflow BigQueryHook ValueError: The project_id should be set

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, airflow, hook

I am trying to fetch data from a big query table using BigQueryHook and I am facing this error

```
File "/home/abdul/etl-pipelines/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/providers/google/cloud/hooks/bigquery.py", line 2061, in run_query
   raise ValueError("The project_id should be set")
ValueError: The project_id should be set
```

I have tried exporting the `AIRFLOW_CON_BIGQUERY_DEFAULT` environment variable still it didn't help. The way I did it.

```
export AIRFLOW_CONN_BIGQUERY_DEFAULT="google-cloud-platform://?extra__google_cloud_platform__project=<gcp_project_id>"
```

Here is my function

```
def get_data_from_bq(**kwargs):
    hook = BigQueryHook(delegate_to=None, use_legacy_sql=False)
    hook.run_query('SELECT max(created_date) FROM `dataset.table`')
```

Although I tried to put `project_id` as an argument in `BigQueryHook` it gave me Unexpected argument error

Tried the second way using the BigQueryHook object

```
hook.project_id = project_id
```

Got the same ValueError.

I went through every piece of documentation and still couldn't find any solution maybe I am missing something?

[Airflow BigQueryHook Docs](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-google/stable/_api/airflow/providers/google/cloud/hooks/bigquery/index.html#airflow.providers.google.cloud.hooks.bigquery.BigQueryHook)

Comment: Have you tried explicitly defining the variable in your code? Something like `BigQueryHook(gcp_conn_id="AIRFLOW_CONN_BIGQUERY_DEFAULT")`?

Comment: It gives error ```airflow.exceptions.AirflowNotFoundException: The conn_id `AIRFLOW_CONN_BIGQUERY_DEFAULT` isn't defined```

Comment: You can try manually creating a connection named `AIRFLOW_CONN_BIGQUERY_DEFAULT` using the airflow UI by following this https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/howto/connection.html#creating-a-connection-with-the-ui. `Conn Id` for your case would be "AIRFLOW_CONN_BIGQUERY_DEFAULT", Google Cloud as the `Conn Type`, input your project id in `Project Id` and you may also try to indicate your service account's json keyfile path on the `Keyfile Path`.